# Listening for SMTP works when server and request is local but if doing the request from a remote server it fails

Tags: c#, php, smtp

I am working on a project where I am making my own SMTP server. This is pretty much working but there is a bit of a problem.

When I run my SMTP server on my development machine and have a php script to send the email or telnet from my local computer to the local smtp server it works fine and my program receives the SMTP messages and I send the relevant responses.

I am then copying the program on to a server and running my smtp server and when I telnet from the server to the local smtp server i.e. `telnet localhost 25` it works.

If I then try and connect to my smtp server through a remote PC on the same network and attempt to telnet to it I get `Connecting to 192.168.1.74 (this is the address of the server)...could not open connection to the host, on port 25: connect failed` and if I run the php script `http://192.168.1.74/send-mail.php` it fails.

On the smtp server code when I bind the socket I have tried binding to 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.74 on port 25 but it makes no difference.

Why would this not be working from a remote PC making the connection to the server but locally it works fine.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Have you got a firewall blocking port 25 on the server?

Comment: Try to bind to `IPAddress.Any`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out what the problem was, I was being dumb, when I set the network card to be static I forgot to add the default gateway. Now that I have done that it is working now as expected.

Thanks everyone for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

A couple stabs in the dark here, but:

1. Does the server have a firewall running? If so, have you made the appropriate exceptions for port 25?
2. Is the remote PC *really* on the same network (i.e. same subnet)? If you've got a router in between you'll have to forward the port appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, there is no firewall running and it is definetely on the same network, its a home network so everything is plugged into one router. Also, I don't think it would make a difference, but the server is running on a virtual machine on top of my dev machine, I can connect to the server for everything else

Comment: Can the dev machine connect to the server from outside the virtual machine? I'm wondering if the dev machine isn't forwarding port 25 through to the VM properly.

Comment: Just did a test, I enabled postfix on the server to see if it was just a problem with my own smtp server, and I am having the same issue, locally it works via localhost but if I telnet from the dev machine to the server it fails to connect